# Plot several graphs of a function density distribution using Table

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I would like to plot the density distribution graphs of the eigenfunction `en[B][[2, 1]]` when a parameter `B` is changed.
But the code does not work if I try to plot the density distribution in the form:
`Table[DensityPlot[ps[B], {r, 0, 10}, {z, -10, 10},  FrameLabel -> {r, z}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",  PlotPoints -> 105, PlotLegends -> Automatic], {B, {0, 10, 20}}]`

Could you please show me how to write this part of the code correctly

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
rmax = 20;
zmax = 20;
HC = Simplify[-1/2*
     Laplacian[u[r, z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] - 
    1/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]*u[r, z]+(B^2)*u[r, z]];

en[BB_] := 
  Module[{}, {vals, funs} = 
    NDEigensystem[{HC + u[r, z]} /. B -> BB, 
     u[r, z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 10, 
     Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}}, 
       "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10000}}];
   Return[{vals[[1 ;; 4]] - 1, funs[[1 ;; 4]]}]];

ps[B_] := en[B][[2, 1]];

Table[DensityPlot[ps[B], {r, 0, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  FrameLabel -> {r, z}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotPoints -> 105, PlotLegends -> Automatic], {B, {0, 10, 20}}]
```

Comment: en[B] is not a function. It returns: {vector, {function, function,..}}

Comment: @Daniel Huber, thanks for the comment! Yes, en[B] is not a function, but I would like to plot ps[B] which is a function of r and z (ps[B_] := en[B][[2, 1]])

Comment: Sorry I misread this. But what does `HC + u[r, z]} /. B -> BB` mean? There is No "B" in  'HC + u[r, z]}'

Comment: @Daniel Huber, thanks! Sorry, It was a typo. I have just added the term (B^2)*u[r, z] in HC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DensityPlot has the Attibute "HoldAll":

```
Attributes[DensityPlot]

{HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}
```

Therefore, if you want to evaluate "ps[B]" before calling "DensityPlot" you have to use "Evaluate":

```
Table[DensityPlot[Evaluate[ps[B]], {r, 0, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  FrameLabel -> {r, z}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotPoints -> 105, PlotLegends -> Automatic], {B, {0, 10, 20}}]
```

[image]